# JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:modulerr] in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, angular-factory

I am implementing logic through ui-router, Factory and Directive but getting error: JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:modulerr]  in Angular Js.

Ui-Routing was working fine.

Index.html file:

```
<html><head><title>Employee Management System</title>
<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/app/EmpRecord.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/app/GetDataService.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/app/EmpController.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/app/EmpApp.js"></script></head>
<body ng-app="EmpApp">
<div class="page-header">Employee Management System
</div><div ng-include="'pageContents/menu.html'"></div>

<ui-view></ui-view></body></html>
```

EmpApp.js

```
var app = angular.module("EmpApp", ['ui.router']);
app.factory('EmpFact', ['$http', EmpFact])
    .controller('EmpController', ['$scope', 'EmpFact',EmpController])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
                 .state('home', {
                     templateUrl: '/home.html'
                           })
                 .state('Add', {
                     templateUrl: '/AddEmployee.html'
                 })
                  .state('List', {

                     templateUrl: 'ListEmp.html',
                     controller: 'EmpController'
                 }
                 )

})

.directive('emp-Record', EmpRecord);
```

ListEmp.html:

```
<div><div><h3>List of Employees</h3></div>
<div EmpRecord ng-repeat="e in Employees"></div></div>
```

EmpController

```
<div><div><h3>List of Employees</h3></div>
<div EmpRecord ng-repeat="e in Employees"></div></div>
```

GetDataService.js

```
 var EmpFact = function ($http) {
 var records = {}
  $http.get('http://localhost/EmployeeApi/api/Emp')
            .then(function (response) {
                records= response.data;
            });

    return {
        GetData: function () {
            alert(records);
            return records;
        }
    }       
 }
```

All Errors are gone Now but data is not coming.

In short:
Controller:

```
var EmpController= function ($scope,EmpFact) {

$scope.Employees = EmpFact.GetData();
console.log($scope.Employees);
```

};

Service:

```
 var EmpFact = function ($http) {
var records = {}
  $http.get('http://localhost/EmployeeApi/api/Emp')
            .then(function (response) {
            records= response.data;
            });

    return {
        GetData: function () {
            alert(records);
            return records;
        }}}
```

Àpp.js

```
app.factory('EmpFact', ['$http', EmpFact])
  .controller('EmpController', ['$scope','EmpFact', EmpController])
.directive('empRecord', function () {
   return {
    template: "<tr><td>{{e.empid}}</td><td>{{e.empName}}</td><td>{{e.empEmail}}</td><td>{{e.empSalary}}</td>"
}});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<div><h3>List of Employees</h3></div>
 <div emp-Record ng-repeat="e in Employees"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: please use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js` and provide the *complete* error message.

Comment: 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module EmpApp due to:

Error: [$compile:baddir] Directive/Component name 'EmpRecord' is invalid. The first character must be a lowercase letter

Comment: I updated naming convention for Directive. Now I am getting error on Controller: TypeError: Unable to get property 'GetData' of undefined or null reference

Comment: the new error says it is in `EmpController.js`, but you haven't included the source for that file in your question.

Comment: @GAURAVMAHAJAN Are you sure you injected the service into the controller, shouldn't it be `.controller('EmpController', ['$scope', 'EmpFact', EmpController])` and of course in the controller function itself you must include it too: `var EmpController = function ($scope, EmpFact) {`

Comment: I think you included js file incorrectly. try include `EmpRecord` ,`EmpRecord` ,`EmpRecord` ,`EmpController`  after `EmpApp.js`

Comment: @HadiJeddizahed But wouldn't it give [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr) in that case?

Comment: Thanks. Errors are gone. But data is not coming.

Comment: @GAURAVMAHAJAN How did they gone? What did you do to make them disappear?

Comment: added 'EmpFact' as injector in Controller Declaration

Comment: Now you need to undertand the concept of asynchronism, and how to use promises. Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/

Comment: I am voting to close the question as too broad at this point.  You have already solved the question you asked, then changed the question, then solved that problem, then changed the question again to ask a 3rd entirely different question.  You have turned the question into a troubleshooting session, which isn't helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so as I suggested in the comment, because the error implies that you haven't injected the `EmpFact` factory into `EmpController`, changing

```
.controller('EmpController', ['$scope', EmpController])
```

Into:

```
.controller('EmpController', ['$scope', 'EmpFact', EmpController])
```

And also injecting it to the controller function:

```
var EmpController = function ($scope, EmpFact) { ... };
```

Made the error disappeared, but now you say that "data is not coming".

I suggest another change in your factory, instead of your current code, try this:

```
var EmpFact = function ($http) {
    return {
        GetData: function () {
            // return a promise which resolve with the actual data returned from the server
            return $http.get('http://localhost/EmployeeApi/api/Emp').then(
                function (response) {
                    // return the actual results, instead of the whole response from the server
                    return response.data;
                }
            );
        }
    }
};
```

Now, in your controller, you should be able to get the data like this:

```
var EmpController = function ($scope, EmpFact) {
    // Call the "GetData" from the factory, which return a promise with the actual results returned from the server
    EmpFact.GetData().then(
        function(data) {
             // in the resolve callback function, save the results data in 
             // any $scope property (I used "$scope.Employees" so it will be 
             // available in the view via {{ Employees | json }})
             $scope.Employees = data;
        }
    );
};
```

By returning a promise you are guaranteed to be able to handle the results returned from an asynchronous request (AJAX). You should be able to use the results in the view like this:

```
 <div emp-Record ng-repeat="e in Employees"></div>
```

(Note that the above HTML snippet is taken from the comments below this answer)

**Edit:**

Looking at your directive, it doesn't look like a correct way to construct a table. Change `emp-Record` to `emp-record` and wrap it in a `<table>` tag to make it a valid HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr emp-record ng-repeat="e in Employees"></tr>
</table>
```

And in your directive's template make sure you **close** the row tag (Add `</tr>`):

```
.directive('empRecord', function () {
    return {
        template: "<tr><td>{{e.empid}}</td><td>{{e.empName}}</td><td>{{e.empEmail}}</td><td>{{e.empSalary}}</td></tr>"
    }
});
```

Comment: After the changes I am getting error: TypeError: Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference. at EmpController (http://localhost:65196/Scripts/app/EmpController.js:2:5)

Comment: var EmpController = function ($scope, EmpFact) {
    $scope.records = EmpFact.GetData().then(function(result){return result.data});
          
}

Comment: @GAURAVMAHAJAN Are you sure you injected 'EmpFact' to the controleler?

Comment: @AlonEitan your GetData() method doesn't do the correct thing, then. You probably forgot `return`.

Comment: var EmpFact = function ($http) {

                    
        return {
            GetData: function () {
                $http.get('http://localhost/EmployeeApi/api/Emp')
                .then(function (response) {

                    return response.data;
                },
                function (response) {
                    return response;
                } );
            }}}

Comment: No, sorry. My previous comment was in fact for @GAURAVMAHAJAN

Comment: Sorry. return was missing on line: $http.get('http://localhost/EmployeeApi/api/Emp'). Error gone but data not come

Comment: @GAURAVMAHAJAN Open the developer tools and in the **Network** tab, check that there is a get request to `http://localhost/EmployeeApi/api/Emp` also make sure that you **didn't** try something like `$scope.records = EmpFact.GetData();` because it will **not work**

Comment: After clicking on URL I am getting data in chrome: I made that Web API in ASP.NET and using in multiple projects

Comment: Do you see an OPTIONS request, or a GET request, or both?

Comment: @GAURAVMAHAJAN Try adding `alert(1);`  or even better: `console.log(data);` inside  `EmpFact.GetData().then(function(data) { .... });` - Do you get an alert, or do you see the results showing in the console (if you decided to add `console.log(data)`)?

Comment: is that good in html:  <div emp-Record ng-repeat="e in Employees"></div>

Comment: .directive('empRecord', function () {

    return {
        template: "<tr><td>{{e.empid}}</td><td>{{e.empName}}</td><td>{{e.empEmail}}</td><td>{{e.empSalary}}</td>"
    }
});

Comment: @GAURAVMAHAJAN Oh, no - In the controller function, change `$scope.records = data;` to `$scope.Employees = data;`

Comment: console.log is returning object array

Comment: @GAURAVMAHAJAN Take a look at my last edit, see if it help. If not, please include an example of the data returned from the server in order to debug the reason for why you don't get data in the view

Comment: I am getting if I write http.get in controller directly but I dont want to architect this way. This is working: var EmpController = function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost/EmployeeApi/api/Emp')
               .then(function (response) {

                   $scope.Employees = response.data;
               });

}

Comment: @GAURAVMAHAJAN Well in my answer I specifically chained the promise returned from the factory so you don't need to set `response.data` in the controller, because you `return response.data;` already in the factory. Every line in the code on my answer is important and there for a reason

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alon for your help as I am new to Angular, converting my ASP.NET MVC code to HTML5/Angular only.

Finally I am able to resolve it.

Data Service/Factory:

```
 var EmpFact = function ($http) {
    return {
        GetData: function () {
            return $http.get('http://localhost/EmployeeApi/api/Emp');
        }
    }
 }
```

Controller:

```
var EmpController = function ($scope, EmpFact) {
//EmpFact.GetData() is a promise.
EmpFact.GetData().then(
    function (result) {

       $scope.Employees= result.data;
    }
    );
}
```